# Laravel html table

Tags: php, html, laravel-5

I am trying to make a table for private messages that an user receives.

This is my code:

```
<table>
    <?php
    foreach ($mesaje as $mesaj)
    {
        foreach ($users as $user)
            echo '<tr>';


        {
            if ($user->user_id == $mesaj->expeditor_id && Auth::user()->user_id == $mesaj->destinatar_id)
            {
                echo '<td style = " padding: 5px 0px 0px 100px;">' . $user->username . '</td>';
            }

            if (Auth::user()->user_id == $mesaj->destinatar_id)
            {
                echo '
                <td style = " padding: 5px 0px 0px 195px;">' . $mesaj->subiect . '</td>
                <td style = " padding: 5px 0px 0px 215px;">' . $mesaj->data_mesajului . '</td>
                ';
            }
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>'; ?>
</table>
```

`Expeditor_id =` the id of the user that sends the message

`destinatar_id =` the id of the user that receives the message

I want it to be a message then on another line another message(username, the subject and the data), I don't know why some usernames are displayed, some are not, can anyone give me a solution please?

Comment: You want both the cases `true` or one of them `true`?

Comment: well both of them, one is for showing the username of the user who send the message and  one is for showing the subject and data of the message

Comment: make this logic in your controller just retrieve messages that belongs to current user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<table>

    @foreach ($mesaje as $mesaj)
       @foreach ($users as $user)

         @if ($user->user_id == $mesaj->expeditor_id && Auth::user()->user_id == $mesaj->destinatar_id)
                <tr>
                  <td style=" padding: 5px 0px 0px 100px;">{{$user->username}}</td>
                  <td style=" padding: 5px 0px 0px 195px;">{{$mesaj->subiect}}</td>
                  <td style=" padding: 5px 0px 0px 215px;"> {{$mesaj->data_mesajului}}</td>
                </tr>
         @endif
      @endforeach
    @endforeach
</table>
```

Comment: hmm the problem now seems to be that i only get messages from 1 user. if i try to send a message with a different account, that message will appear and the previous one will disappear

Comment: @can you clarify a little bit more

Comment: I have sended 3 messages with 3 different accounts to my 4'th account.Only one user from those 3 is displayed(the last one i send message from),but the subject and the date are displayed for all 3

Comment: i update my answer ,it is laravel take advantage of blade instead of echoing.Do not forget to save your view file as name.blade.php

Answer (score 0):

In your `IF` condition you need to use second `IF` condition

FOR Example :

```
<table>
    <?php
    foreach ($mesaje as $mesaj)
    {
        foreach ($users as $user)
            echo '<tr>';


        {
            if ($user->user_id == $mesaj->expeditor_id && Auth::user()->user_id == $mesaj->destinatar_id)
            {
                echo '<td style = " padding: 5px 0px 0px 100px;">' . $user->username . '</td>';

               if (Auth::user()->user_id == $mesaj->destinatar_id)
               {
                echo '
                <td style = " padding: 5px 0px 0px 195px;">' . $mesaj->subiect . '</td>
                <td style = " padding: 5px 0px 0px 215px;">' . $mesaj->data_mesajului . '</td>
                ';
              }
            }


        }
    }
    echo '</tr>'; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: uhm it is not working because i need to show the message only to the reciever and the reciever must see the name of the sender

Comment: I have update code. i have change the position of second `IF` condition check this one. This should work

Comment: hmm the problem now seems to be that i only get messages from 1 user. if i try to send a message with a different account, that message will appear and the previous one will disappear